# Azure service Bus get all queue message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

i am using azure service bus queue. but i am not able to get all message from queue using "get all queue message (peek Lock): Microsoft built in api.

Is there any way to get all queue messages?

> {
>       "$connections": {
>           "value": {
>               "servicebus_1": {
>                   "connectionId": "/subscriptions/c776fec3-6aec-4722-b099-b054c267b240/resourceGroups/Plugin-Resource/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-3",
>                   "connectionName": "servicebus-3",
>                   "id": "-b054c267b240/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/servicebus"
>               }
>           }
>       },
>       "definition": {
>           "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
>           "actions": {
>               "Get_messages_from_a_queue_(peek-lock)": {
>                   "inputs": {
>                       "host": {
>                           "api": {
>                               "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-northcentralus.azure-apim.net/apim/servicebus"
>                           },
>                           "connection": {
>                               "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus_1']['connectionId']"
>                           }
>                       },
>                       "method": "get",
>                       "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('email-listener')}/messages/batch/peek",
>                       "queries": {
>                           "maxMessageCount": 20,
>                           "queueType": "Main"
>                       }
>                   },
>                   "runAfter": {},
>                   "type": "ApiConnection"
>               }
>           },
>           "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
>           "outputs": {},
>           "parameters": {
>               "$connections": {
>                   "defaultValue": {},
>                   "type": "Object"
>               }
>           },
>           "triggers": {
>               "Recurrence": {
>                   "recurrence": {
>                       "frequency": "Day",
>                       "interval": 3
>                   },
>                   "type": "Recurrence"
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }

thanks

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: i am using azure logic app

Answer (score 0):

The managed API by default returns 20 messages.
[image]

You'll need to manually increase the max message count if you have more than 20 messages in your queue.

[image]